# How to create a custom field type?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I can see the following field types as default in share-point 2013, [image]

But, I want to create a custom field type here, for the example consider 'slider' is a new field that is available after 'Managed Metadata', So What i want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SharePoint 2007/2010, you can inherit from OOB field types and create a new field type. Following articles can help you get started:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb861799(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb861799%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2012/02/05/developing-custom-field-type-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

If you are using SharePoint 2013, you can create custom fields using a new technique called *client-side rendering*.

> With SharePoint 2013, we can modify the presentation and validation of
>   a custom field (or technically any field) on any form in SharePoint as
>   well as in Views simply via JavaScript.  This is an incredibly
>   powerful capability.  It provides a nice, easy, standard (and
>   supported) way of customizing the end user experience to be more
>   efficient and friendly.

References:

http://blog.aptillon.com/2012/10/12/custom-field-types-in-sharepoint-2013-apps/
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Create-eb30a620
http://spdevlab.com/2013/06/09/custom-field-type-for-sharepoint-2013-visa-card-field-sample/

Comment: Hi Nadeem Yousuf, Do you have any video link for your solution...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPhYXgKRKq8

Comment: Unfortunately the statement "If you are using SharePoint 2013, you can create custom fields using a new technique called client-side rendering" is not correct. CSR has nothing to-do with creating fields(in fact OP is asking field types), it is about customizing the rendering of existing or custom fields

Answer (score 4):

It depends, deploying custom field types is not supported for SharePoint Online.
According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615464.aspx):

> Only fields that use a built-in SharePoint Foundation field type, or a
>   custom field type that is previously installed in a farm solution, are
>   possible. A custom field type cannot be deployed in a sandboxed
>   solution.

Custom field types could be deployed as a *farm solution* only since field type definitions require a `fldtype*.xml` file to be deployed to the hive.

---

Instead of creating *custom field type*, you could *reuse* existing field type, for example `Number` field type  and then

- *create a field* for storing Slider values
- *create a rendering template* that renders this field as a Slider

Please follow [this article](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/sharepoint-2013/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/) as an introductory to CSR and how to customize the rendering of a field.

Comment: I agree, CSR is a great feature, but I think it's not powerful enough. Every time you create a new view you need to include the js for the rendering. Furthermore, there is no way to include CSR on personal views.