# Reordering documents within a document library

Tags: 2013, document-library

Is there a way to manually order documents within a document library in SharePoint 2013? What I want is an ability to grab a document and drag it and release to a different position; once I release it, items in the document library should be reordered to new positions. Is there any out-of-the-box approach to achieve this?

Comment: There is no default behaviour. The drag-drop is not difficult to program, but you need a Metadata field to store the order in.

Comment: Why a metadata field? I'd use simple integer field.

Answer (score 1):

As @DannyEngelman correctly points out in his comment, there is no OOTB way for doing this.

Integer field as you suggest yourself is one way, but hell to maintain.

If you are working with an on-prem solution I'd rather suggest you create your own custom FieldType in which you can maintain an order - take a look at [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97958/how-to-create-a-custom-field-type) for guidance.